# RegExp - replace the `html` tags on search and highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am doing a search and highlight process using `regex`, the problem i am facing is, it's accounts the `html` tags too search option.

since the `html` element replaces, i am getting bad result. how to avoid this?

here is my patter to search and replace the `html` text to `mark` tag.

```js
var src_str = $("#test").html();
var origional = $("#backup").html();

var searchIt = function (text) {
    console.log(text);

    var marks = text;    
         marks = marks.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+marks+")", "gi");
    
    src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");
    
    $("#test").html(src_str);
   
}


var resetIt = function (Text) {
    $("#parent").html(origional);
    if(!Text.length) return;
    searchIt(Text);
}

$('#keyWord').keyup(function (e){
    var inputText = $.trim($(e.target).val());
    resetIt(inputText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="test">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="backup" >
   <div id="test">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</script>
<input type="text" id="keyWord" />
<button>Reset </button>
```

Comment: provide a sample input along with expected output.

Comment: please visit my jsfiddle, this is for search purpose. i would like to highlight the letter(s) which is typed in input box. when the input box empty, all highlight need to removed. - any more info let me know

Comment: it takes long time to enter into that page. Why don't you use our built-in tool?

Comment: do you facing any issue? it works fine for me. and i don't know how to put in to build-in-tool. if you help let  me do.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - snippet added please check

Comment: Try this pattern    <(.+?)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like your problem is that you're inserting `<mark>...</mark>` tags around your search results to highlight them and later matches can't match around these as well?

I was able to get it working like this:

```js
var src_str = $("#test").html();
var origional = $("#backup").html();

var searchIt = function (text) {
    console.log(text);

    var marks = text;    
         marks = marks.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+marks+"+(?=[^>]*(?:<|\Z)))", "gi");
    src_str = src_str.replace(/<\/?mark.*?>/gi,"")        
    src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");
    
    $("#test").html(src_str);
   
}


var resetIt = function (Text) {
    $("#parent").html(origional);
    if(!Text.length) return;
    searchIt(Text);
}

$('#keyWord').keyup(function (e){
    var inputText = $.trim($(e.target).val());
    resetIt(inputText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="test">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="backup" >
   <div id="test">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</script>
<input type="text" id="keyWord" />
<button>Reset </button>
```

Comment: When you input "b", then the bold gets messed up, is there a way to avoid replacing anything that is inside an HTML-tag?

Comment: @RolandSeuhs Rebuilt it. This answer had a lot of problems, but seems to be working now.